# What is the meaning of a inner system/transfer function?

Tags: filters, filter-design

In an academic paper I'm currently reading [1], the notion of an **inner** system is central. It is defined as follows

> A *(linear)* system $G$ *(with $m$ inputs and $p$ outputs)*
>    is called **inner** if it satisfies $G^T (z^{-1}) G (z) = I_m$

Further along the article it is said that

> an inner function has all poles within the unit circle, and all zeros outside the circle.

which would mean that an *inner* function is always a (*stable*) *non-minimum phase* transfer function.
Are there other implications of the notion of *inner* function in terms of system characteristics? What does it truly mean for a system to be *inner*?

Thanks in advance.

> [1] Heuberger, P. S.; Van den Hof, P. M. & Bosgra, O. H. A generalized orthonormal basis for linear dynamical systems IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control, IEEE, 1995, 40, 451-465

Comment: It's pretty obvious but nonetheless relevant that the system will be stable (as all its poles are within the unit circle). Apart from that, what comes to my mind is that property of rational systems that states that the square of the magnitude of the frequency response is the evaluation on the unit circle of $G(z)G^{*}(1/z^{*})$. AFAIK, that works for SISO systems, but maybe you find this useful.

Comment: The implication of stability is indeed obvious (I have edited my question to include it). The property you mentionned may be related beacuse, for a MIMO system evaluated on the unit circle, $G(z) G^*(1/z^*) = G(z) (G^T(z))^*$, and the definition of _inner system_ gives that $G^T(1/z) G(z) = G^T(z^*) G(z) = I_m$. But it doesn't help me get to the bottom of this notion....